# Should "instead" always be followed by a comma at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I have a personal rule. If what follows "instead' is a complete sentence, I include a comma. If it's an incomplete sentence, I don't. I decided this after checking out real examples:

> Instead, he sleeps beneath a blanket on a mattress with a built-in
>   pillow shape. Source.
>
> Instead approach the hiring manager as if you were a consultant or
>   collaborator.

([Source](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22instead%20%22%20%2Fr%3As&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) of the examples.)

Is this a sound rule? A grammatical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it should come after comma.
Instead,I kissed her.
It may come before instead.
Sade beg him, instead of abusing her.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use a comma after "Instead" at the start of a sentence if what comes next is a full sentence.

> Don't try to open the safe without unlocking it. Instead, enter the code into the front panel and then turn the handle.

The same structure applies to using other words:

> However, if the safe door is already open then disregard the previous instruction.
>
> Nevertheless, leaving a safe door open is generally regarded as a bad idea.

You might choose to use a semicolon instead of starting a new sentence:

> Don't try to open the safe without unlocking it; instead, enter the code into the front panel and then turn the handle.

Of course, if what comes next is not a full sentence then you do not need a comma:

> Don't try to open the safe without unlocking it. Instead of immediately turning the handle, enter the code first.